# <Control-x> binding not working in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Whenever I try to bind a text widget with `"<Control-x>"` , I keep getting an error that says:

`_tkinter.TclError: PRIMARY selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined`

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def cut_text(event):
    selected = text.selection_get()
    clipboard_label.config(text = clipboard_label['text'] + f"\t{selected}")

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

clipboard_label = Label(root , text = "Your Clipboard History:" , font = "arial 11")
clipboard_label.grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

root.bind("<Control-x>" , cut_text)

mainloop()
```

As I keep getting that error , I tried this:

```
def cut_text(event):
    selected = text.get("sel.first" , "sel.last")
    clipboard_label.config(text = clipboard_label['text'] + f"\t{selected}")
```

But when I do that , I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"
```

I don't face this problem with any other binding like `"<Control-c>"` , but this problem only occurs when I use the `"<Control-x>"` binding.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: The problem is your hotkey, when you press control and x, there is nothing left in the selection and hence the error. Change to `root.bind("<Control-f>" , cut_text)` and you will see it work.

Comment: Yes , I did realize that , but that's what my problem is exactly about. By default, using the combination of Control+x will cut the text. But I don't want that. What I want is the text widget should remove the default binding of this key combination and it should only execute what is in my function. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can return `'break'` for this purpose. Like:

```
text.bind("<Control-x>" , cut_text)
root.bind('<Control-x>',lambda e: 'break')
```

What `'break'` does is, it overrides the default behaviour(sort-ish). I could link you to a nicely written documentation, but [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) is currently down.